# How to route packets whose destination are in an ipset to a nat interface

Tags: iptables

I have an interface named em2, which is a nat interface. I want to route all the packets whose destination are in an ipset named test to em2.

If I don't use ipset and policy routing, it works well

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o em2  -j MASQUERADE
ip route add 1.1.1.1 via 10.1.1.13 dev em2
```

But if I use policy routing and ipset

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o em2  -j MASQUERADE
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add default via 10.1.1.13 dev em2 table 100
ipset create test hash:ip
ipset add test 1.1.1.1
iptables -t mangle -N TEST_ROUTE
iptables -t mangle -A TEST_ROUTE -m set --match-set test dst -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j TEST
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j TEST
```

The problem is all the packets route to em2 perfectly, but the response packet can't be received. According to the capture of tcpdump, it seems the response packet did not do the nat correctly. What did I miss?

The capture of tcpdump show as the following, 10.1.1.14 is the address of em2

```
18:57:39.696669 IP 10.1.1.14.40169 > 1.1.1.1.53: 28094+ [1au] A? www.google.com. (55)
18:57:39.753114 IP 1.1.1.1.53 > 10.1.1.14.40169: 28094 1/0/1 A 142.250.66.100 (59)
18:57:44.701781 IP 10.1.1.14.40169 > 1.1.1.1.53: 28094+ [1au] A? www.google.com. (55)
18:57:44.745936 IP 1.1.1.1.53 > 10.1.1.14.40169: 28094 1/0/1 A 142.250.66.100 (59)
18:57:49.706916 IP 10.1.1.14.40169 > 1.1.1.1.53: 28094+ [1au] A? www.google.com. (55)
18:57:49.750357 IP 1.1.1.1.53 > 10.1.1.14.40169: 28094 1/0/1 A 142.251.220.4 (59)
```

I can see 1.1.1.1 reply with the packet, but dig got nothing.

Comment: does `/sbin/sysctl -ar \\.rp_filter` answer 1 anywhere? Anyway could you provide a sample of such capture (as text)?

Comment: Yes, rp_filter = 1

Comment: @A.B  thanks very much, rp_filter = 0 solve the problem

Comment: This is not the best way (considering rp_filter is a security feature), but anyway if you're fine with this, then fine.